# What causes the ClassCastException: java.util.TreeSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable?

Tags: java, collections, treemap

So I'm trying to move all Strings of a certain length from a Collection of Strings (could either be a Set or a List) to a TreeMap and setting a Set of the characters in each String as the key for that String
but the line `map.put(keyRinger(word), word);` throws `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`

```
Map<Set<Character>, String> map = new TreeMap<Set<Character>, String>();
for (String words : words)    {
  if (word.length() == length)  {
    map.put(keyRinger(word), word);
  }
}
```

This is the `keyRing` method in case you're curious.

```
private Set<Character> keyRinger(String current)  { 
  Set<Character> keyRing = new TreeSet<Character>();
  for (int i = 0; i < current.length(); i++)   {
    char key = current.charAt(i); 
    keyRing.add(key);
  }
  return keyRing;
}
```

So my question is what can I do to avoid this? I've read I need a `Comparator` or to implement `Comparable` but I don't know how to do that, and I think there might be a simpler solution (although perhaps not as efficient).

Comment: "So I'm trying to convert a Collection of Strings (could either be a Set or a List) to a TreeMap" - could you elaborate? If the input is a collection of strings, why is the output a map? What do the keys and values represent? And why are you using a TreeMap instead of HashMap?

Comment: I'm not really sure why you need reasons for what objects I'm using, I need to use a TreeMap and I need to convert a Collection of Strings into the values of a TreeMap. I know a HashMap would eliminate this problem, but I have to use a TreeMap.

Comment: Well, if you need a TreeMap (dunno why you would), you'll have to define a Comparator to compare your sets. There's no way around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll notice the javadoc of [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) states

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by
>   a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which
>   constructor is used.

So if you don't provide a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), it will use *natural ordering*. What is natural ordering? The javadoc of the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface states

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class
>   that implements it. **This ordering is referred to as the class's
>   natural ordering,** and the class's compareTo method is referred to as
>   its natural comparison method.

So your key element in your `TreeMap` must implement `Comparable`. You are trying to use `TreeSet` instances as keys in your `TreeMap`. [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) does not implement `Comparable`.

You get a `ClassCastException` when `TreeMap` tries to cast the key to a `Comparable` reference in order to use its `compareTo` method.

To correct this issue, you should create a `TreeMap` by providing your own custom `Comparator` for comparing `Set<Character>` instances.

Comment: So a custom `Comparator` would be a seperate method? How would I call that in this code?

Comment: @Mxt `Comparator` is an interface. You need to create a class that implements this interface and provide an instance of it to your `TreeMap` constructor expression. The `TreeMap` will use it internally.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can create the comparator class:

```
public class NutrientByInclusionOrderComparator  implements Comparator<ProductNutrient>{

@Override
public int compare(ProductNutrient o1, ProductNutrient o2) {
    if (o1 == null && o2 == null){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (o1 == null){
        return -1;
    }
    else if (o2 == null){
        return 1;
    }
    else if ( o1.getNumOrder().compareTo(o2.getNumOrder()) == 0) {
        return o1.getDtInclusion().compareTo(o2.getDtInclusion());
    } else {
        return o1.getNumOrder().compareTo(o2.getNumOrder());
    }
}

}
```

And then, when creating your TreeSet:

```
Set<ProductNutrient> productNutrients = new TreeSet<ProductNutrient>(new NutrientByInclusionOrderComparator());
```

Cheers!