# Why Map interface does not restrict key generic type to extend Comparable?

Tags: java, collections

From what I can tell java casts a key while making comparison and if a key does not implement Comparable interface you'll get an exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: maps.TreeMapExample$A cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable` which is `RuntimeException`.

Why it does not explicitly require **K** to extend **Comparable** interface in the Class signature, e.g. `public interface Map<K extends Comparable,V> {` for compiler to check it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HashMap does not need keys to be Comparable but still implements Map interface. Only TreeMap has this requirement.

Moreover TreeMap can be used with non Comparable keys too, [provided a comparator at creation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592485/what-causes-the-classcastexception-java-util-treeset-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lan)

Comment: Actually, it is not `TreeMap` which has this requirement but `SortedMap`.